# When were control flow features added to CoreImage?

Tags: ios, macos, core-image

I remember in [years prior](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CIKernelLangRef/ci_gslang_ext.html) (under the *Unsupported Items* header) that I could not use `if for while` when writing CoreImage kernels, but [now I can](https://developer.apple.com/metal/CoreImageKernelLanguageReference11.pdf) (under the *Control Flow* header).

What version of macOS and iOS first allow this language style?

Note that I do see the different copyright years, but that's not definitive as to what version of the OS it correlates to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was watching the 2015 WWDC videos and found that it was noted as a new feature for that convention. Seeing as OS X 10.11 was released 30 September 2015, it would be logical that that would be the first OS release that supported this feature.